# SQL - Sparse Tables, total size and cell space

Tags: sql-server

Alright, so I've been working on a project in which I need to create a SQL 'wide table' or a SQL table that can handle more than +1,000 columns of data. To establish an example, let's say that out of 1502 columns in a row:

- 1 column is dedicated to an "ID **INT** PRIMARY KEY"
- 5 columns are dedicated for file info using "FileInfo_1 **VARCHAR(20) SPARSE**, ..."
- 1,495 columns are dedicated to storing numbers with decimals using "number_info_1 **REAL SPARSE**, ..."
- The last column contains the column set information using "columnSet **XML COLUMN_SET FOR ALL_SPARSE_COLUMNS**"

When I run a test string in my sql of:

`INSERT Test_table(ID, FileInfo_1, FileInfo_2, ...) VALUE(0, 'string1', 'string2', ..., 0.1234, 1.2345, ...)`

I run into the **problem** were **the maximum amount of row space goes beyond the 8,060 bytes limit**. But given what i have, shouldn't the total space be less than 8,060? Since int takes 4 bytes, the 5 varchar(20) cells should take 100 bytes (or 10 bytes, I'm not too sure) and the 1,495 real cells should take 5,980 bytes, all of it which is less than 8,060.

I did some testing on how much data is used per real cell and for every real cell I delete, I get 8 bytes back. Which doesn't make sense to me since it should be just 4 bytes, correct?

Can anyone offer me some insight as to why this is happening? I'm new to this and I'm not exactly sure why real cells are taking 8 bytes instead of 4.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are different products. Sparse columns are a  Are you asking about MySQL or SQL Server ?

Comment: I'm asking for a SQL Server, a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard to be specific that is running on a local machine.

Comment: Sparse columns make sense when you *don't* intend to fill all of them. If you only store, eg 100 real values each time, you can have many thousands of columns. The values are stored in the columnset field which takes more space than individual columns would. Sparse columns don't help if you fill a large proprtion of columns for each row.

Comment: I see, so in your opinion, what would be a good way to get around making tables with more than 1024 columns of data per row? The only solution i have come up with is to perhaps dividing the 1500 columns into three tables. One table that acts as a reference for the other two and two tables with 750 columns of data each.

Comment: Who is going to consume the data? If it is an application, you could store all of it in a blob and have the application parse it. If you need to access individual values from SQL, you'd need to partition

Comment: Yeah, it needs to be accessed individually from Sql. I'll take your suggestion and parse it. Once again, thank you very much for your help, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-null sparse column values actually take *more* space than non-sparse values. Sparse columns are useful when you want to store many columns that are NULL most of the time.

The article [Use Sparse Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx) from the documentation shows that `real` values take 8 bytes when a non-spare column would only need 4 bytes. If you fill all of them each time, you'd need 11960 bytes.

The article shows how many columns would have to be null per type to achieve a 40% space reduction. In your case, you'd need ~590 real columns to be null.

If you need to fill all 1495 values for each row, you should partition the table vertically.

If you don't need to access individual values from SQL, an option is to store all the data in a blob field eg a `varbinary(max)` or `nvarchar(max)` field. In this case only the consuming application would be able to use the data. This also prevents you from using any indexes on these values

Comment: Thank you very much for your help